# ios 6 emojis source images

Tags: ios6

So, just where can I download the emoji icons? Say, I want to use them in my desktop application?  Don't care much about the encoding, I just need the icons.

I've gone through a lot of websites but all I can see is screenshots of them altogether.

Comment: [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ドコモ絵文字&hl=en&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0)

Comment: @ring0, thanks for this, but I'll be needing them separately (as in one image per block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icons are a font, not individual images, on iOS and Mac OS X.